# Why does the same code what works in Windows, does not in CentOS 7?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Basically, I have a java program what gets data from websites using Selenium (Chromedriver)

The same java program works without any errors on windows, that's when I haven't done any mistakes.
In CentOS 7, it works, but throws a few errors & is weird.

Errors:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-6" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code                                  500. Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that C                                 hrome has crashed.)
Host info: host: 'instance-20221128-2304', ip: '10.0.0.105'
Build info: version: '4.6.0', revision: '79f1c02ae20'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-1160.76.1.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_352'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--headless], exten                                 sions: []}}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--headless], extensions: [                                 ]}}}]
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:146)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:101)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:67)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:156)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:167)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:142)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:541)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:242)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:157)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:101)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:81)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:70)
        at org.hinoob.bot.BangerFM.fetch(BangerFM.java:55)
        at org.hinoob.bot.BangerFM.lambda$startLoop$0(BangerFM.java:26)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)`
```

I've followed this guide to install the things: https://www.usessionbuddy.com/post/How-To-Install-Selenium-Chrome-On-Centos-7/

My google chrome version in CentOS:
Google Chrome 107.0.5304.121

I didn't try anything yet, since I don't know what to try.
I expected it to work same as in Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Selenium 4.6.0 Released! selenium Introducing Selenium Manager**
Now you dont need to add driver path or anything. Now selenium automatically update driver.

In your case i guess this issue is for chrome driver compatibility issues.

Update your selenium version, If its a maven project then add following dependency

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And then remove system property if you added chromedriver path manually, Hope your problem will solved.

**Another checkpoint which cause issue for open browser**

1. Make sure chrome is installed in the server/pc
2. If server is headless then add argument --headless
3. Add disable GPU argument

Reference
https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/